# How is the "SQL" part of NoSQL executed?

Tags: java, sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

So I want to dive into a more infused NoSQL with SQL mix but I don't understand how the "SQL" part of NoSQL is executed. This is more for academic purposes then anything but my final goal is to create an SQL translation system that will convert to this.

So I have my query expression:

```
Map<String, AttributeValue> map = new HashMap<String, AttributeValue>();
map.put(":val1", new AttributeValue().withS(partitionKey));
map.put(":val2", new AttributeValue().withS(sortKey.toString()))

DynamoDBQueryExpression<Translate> queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<Translate>()
.withKeyConditionExpression("lang = :val1 AND clang >= :val2")
.withExpressionAttributeValues(map);
```

So my question is:

How does this string `"lang = :val1 AND clang >= :val2"` work, how much/little can I really manipulate it, and does it go directly into SQL?
For instance, why does AWS force use to put `:val1` instead of `"lang = "+val1` for instance. I tried searching through the source code and documentation a few times but cant seem to find the part that addresses this exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the SQL you are referring to is the ANSI/ISO standard used by traditional RDBMS systems such as MySQL/Oracle/etc..

Most NoSQL databases, DynamoDB included, does not adhere to the standard and does not try to implement it (not even close).

The DynamoDB "query language" you are referring to can be thought of more as an SDK manipulation rather than a language. The SDK translates the "language" to the specific API calls used in DynamoDB just to be more user friendly. The engine is not intended to parse these queries and create a query execution plan.